# Smart GWT: Combobox Item pick list issue

Tags: smartgwt

I am using Start GWT 2.5. I am using combobox item. While opening a pick list and if pick list is having only one option, it shows horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Image is attached representing the issue.

**Code:**

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setIsGroup(true);
form.setCellPadding(5);
form.setNumCols(2);

ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem("TestCombo");
comboBoxItem.setValueMap("test1");
form.setFields(comboBoxItem);
form.draw();
```

Can any one help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old post. But it might help someone.

This issue has been resolved in the newer versions of SmartGWT. All the releases above SmartGWT 2.5 reflects that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same issue, and in my experience it only occurs in Google Chrome in **development mode**. Try debugging in Firefox, by using the Firefox plugin which can be [found here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/). That ought to provide a workaround to the problem.

**Note:** if the problem still occurs in Google Chrome after you've deployed your application, I strongly recommend that you open a ticket at the [SmartGWT Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lefke123. & sorry that we forgot to mention that we're getting this problem in Mozilla FF & not in IE. So are you sure that you don't get it in FF?

Comment: Yes, I have to note that I'm developing on Ubuntu 10.10 x64 though, with FF 7 and Chrome 15. Which version of FF are you using? And the issue isn't there on Chrome?

Comment: No. I'm not getting this issue in Chrome, IE, Opera & Safari. I'm getting it only in FF in both compiled & developement mode. I'm using FF 3.6.x with Windows XP as OS.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue now, it's definitely a bug; you could create an issue for it, or try your luck on the SmartGWT forums. Only thing's that left, is to try switching from Jetty to Tomcat during development/compiled modes. (If that provides a workaround.)